# Spring boot 2.0 with swagger ui not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to integrate Spring Boot 2.0 with swagger but not showing up end points.When I looked to developer console on network tab ,it says that I couldn't find "http://localhost:8080/swagger-resources/configuration/ui" and return 404.

Comment: which swagger implementation you are using ?
.. Try to hit url as http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Please add more info: do you use springfox, do you have an existing controllers or will using codegen, do you have a Oauth or another security configured with your SpringBoot?

Comment: If you can also post what your application.properties looks like. I ran into the same issue where all my configurations and swagger documentation end points are working until I specify 
**spring.resources.static-locations[0]=file:src/main/resources/static/** and **spring.resources.static-locations[1]=classpath:/static/**

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem by adding resource handler for swagger:

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    //...irrelevant code here

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have @EnableWebMvc or @WebMvcConfigurationSupport annotation anywhere in the project then remove these or add custom resource handlers to configure swagger-ui.

Here's some common solutions:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2396#issuecomment-402150402