# Swagger with Spring Boot 2.0 leads to 404 error page

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm trying to integrate my Spring Boot version  `2.0.1.RELEASE` with [Swagger](https://swagger.io/).

From this [blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)  it seemed like it will be easy by just adding two Maven dependencies and everything should work.

So I added the following dependencies to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And created the `SwaggerConfig` bean:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
        return docket;
    }
}
```

And in the properties file I ended up with these 3 entries during the attempts to make it work:

```yaml
spring.application.name=cat-service
management.server.servlet.context-path=/cat-service
server.servlet.contextPath=/cat-service
```

But at the end, when accessing

`http://localhost:8080/cat-service/api/v2/api-docs`

or the UI page at

`http://localhost:8080/cat-service/swagger-ui.html`

I get  a `page not found` error.

I found [this issues in the swagger github page](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2155)  and [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586658/spring-boot-2-0-with-swagger-ui-not-working-properly)  but I was not able to change my `404` error.

Comment: You also need the proper configuration including the `@EnableSwagger2` annotation as mentioned in the article. Do you have those, and if so, could you post that in your question as well?

Comment: Did you add the swaggerconfiguration?

Comment: spring-security-rest is not applicable for you

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Added Springfox Swagger-UI and it's not working, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151540/added-springfox-swagger-ui-and-its-not-working-what-am-i-missing)

Comment: I was looking for an answer but I didn't notice that I used swagger 3.0 version with different url `swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: [See more usefull informations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151540/added-springfox-swagger-ui-and-its-not-working-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was able to make it work with Spring boot version `2.0.4.RELEASE` and [this blog post](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-swagger-springfox/):

I added these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And this configuration file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And it worked.

The Swagger UI can be reached at /swagger-ui.html#

Comment: spring-boot 2.6.2 onwards better to go with springdoc-ui

Answer (score 32):

Please check the reference: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

"2.1.3. Migrating from existing 2.x version"

You can remove springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui from your pom.xml and add springfox-boot-starter instead (for example version 3.0.0). Also you can remove the @EnableSwagger2 annotations

And: "**swagger-ui location has moved from** *https://host/context-path/swagger-ui.html* **to** *https://host/context-path/swagger-ui/index.html* OR *https://host/context-path/swagger-ui/* for short. This makes it work much better with pulling it as a web jar and turning it off using configuration properties if not needed."

Comment: the path of the ui page made it work - swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 17):

### OpenAPI

Just use **springdoc-openapi-ui** instead.

The Maven dependency:

```json
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
     <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Or Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11'
```

#### Links

- UI: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
- Json: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
- Yaml: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml

**That's really all there is to it... No annotations / configuration needed. Cheers!**

#### For Spring Security

If you are using **spring security**, make sure you can reach these paths for it to work:

- "/swagger-ui.html" `<-- for UI`
- "/swagger-ui/**" `<-- for UI redirects`
- "/v3/api-docs/**" `<-- for json docs and openapi configuration`
- "/v3/api-docs.yaml" `<-- for yaml docs`

For more information:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

Comment: As of September 2021, this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: I can verify as well that on February 2022 this is the only answer. I just added this as H3AR7B3A7 mentioned and thats it. Added on keycloak (security) the paths and thats it

Comment: I am not using soring security. and i am using spring doc version 1.6.9 . But i am getting same 404 error for swagger-ui. but /v3/api-docs working fine. Is there any other configuration needed

Answer (score 11):

First add SwaggerConfig.java file at the same package of your springboot file like the following example.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
       .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

       registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
       .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
   }

}
```

try this 
`http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/api/swagger-ui.html`
 or 
`http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/swagger-ui.html`

If that does not work, try to change the path in application.properties

Add this to application.properties:

```
server.servlet-path=/loop-service
```

and try the following urls:

`http://localhost:8080/loop-service/swagger-ui.html`  (UI Docs)

`http://localhost:8080/loop-service/v2/api-docs`   (JSON Docs)

Result : 
[image]

Comment: Adding the `addResourceHandlers` did the trick for me. Idk what the code means or does, but thanks 

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue (404 Not Found with springfox 3.0.0). By setting the logging level to "DEBUG", I was able to see endpoints for `/v3/api-docs` and they worked, but there was nothing about "swagger-ui".

I finally found https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3285, which indicates that:

> the new url in 3.0.0 is /swagger-ui/index.html or /swagger-ui/ rather than /swagger-ui.html"

Could they not have added a debug log to indicate where the swagger UI is available?

Answer (score 4):

Springfox swagger UI opens at path `/swagger-ui/index.html`.

Make sure you are allowing correct *ResourceLocations* and *path excluded from interceptors*

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

Note: i'm using Springfox swagger version 3.0.0 and Springboot version 2.5.3

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the `/index.html` part

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I used the WebMvcConfigurer instead of the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter because that class is already deprecated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Bean
  public Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()                
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.illary.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()            
            .apiInfo(metaData());
  }
  private ApiInfo metaData() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Spring Boot Swagger App")
            .description("\"Spring Boot Swagger Server App\"")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
            .build();
  }

  public ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    final ApiInfoBuilder builder = new ApiInfoBuilder();
    builder.title("Swagger Test App").version("1.0").license("(C) Copyright Test")
    .description("The API provides a platform to query build test swagger api");

    return builder.build();
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot, just use the dependency below, it's all it needs to work on the URL `/swagger-ui/` (the trailing slash is mandatory).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Before trying that I was trying to use the classic dependencies of *swagger2* and *swagger-ui*, and none of the suggested URLs were working.

Comment: come on :D one trailing slash was my problem :) thanks but why is it even necessary??

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the location of your Swagger config file; you need to place it at the same package or a subpackage of the spring boot file's.
Like the above picture:

[image: Swagger config and Spring Boot file hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change `server.contextPath` to `server.servlet.contextPath` if you upgrade Spring Boot to 2+.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You just need to remove *@EnableWebMvc* from the configuration classes.

**Description:** *@EnableWebMvc* turn on the class *org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport*. In spring-boot, there is an autoconfiguration class *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration*, which has the annotation *@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)*.

What we get in the end: By adding *@EnableWebMvc* to the project, we ourselves become responsible for everything, since we turn off spring-boot auto-configuration.

Comment: removing it causes `Error creating bean with name webMvcRequestHandlerProvider` among other things...

Answer (score 0):

After adding below line in `application.properties`, it started working

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations: classpath:/webapp/
```

But I'm not sure why do we have to add this.
Adding the code, which I think could be relevant. Dependencies are as below:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And main class as

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class ProxyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ghsatpute.proxy"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this if it can help somebody. This URL worked for me

```
http://localhost:8003/v2/api-docs
```

and for swagger-ui this url worked for me out of the box:

```
http://localhost:8003/swagger-ui.html
```

Check if you are using right configured url for swagger specs. The urls like `http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/api/swagger-ui/`

didn't work , and I had been getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to enable swagger in spring boot application:

1. Add **springfox-swagger2** and **springfox-swagger-ui** dependencies.
2. To enable the Swagger2 in your project you should use **@EnableSwagger2**
3. Define a docket bean ad below

```java
        @Bean
        public Docket docket(){
                return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("group-name").apiInfo(apiInfo()).select().paths(predicate()).build();
        }


        private Predicate<String> predicate() {
                return or(regex("/api/v1.*"), regex("/api/v2.*"));
        }
    
        private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
            return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("The title of the your choice")
                    .contact("your@email.com").license("Licence name ").version("1.0").build();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI url pattern:
`localhost:<server.port>/<server.servlet.context-path>/swagger-ui.html`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for this, using OpenAPI 3.0, not Springfox, I got it running using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` without the need of `@EnableWebMvc`.
The only Dependency needed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I initially just got the JSON and a 404 on the UI.

What ultimately worked was adding the right resource handlers to my `WebConfig` and configuring my `SecurityConfig` to allow unrestricted access for everyone.

The resource handlers in my `WebConfig`:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-initializer.js")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/index.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-ui.css")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/index.css")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-ui-bundle.js")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js");
}
```

Important was to add each one specifically (with version and everything, ** didn't work). Otherwise it wouldn't run in the cloud.

I also needed to add the paths `"/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**"` my `SecurityConfig` to allow access to these resources. So in my case I added those here:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(...
       .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "...")...
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
All I had to do was downgrading the Swagger-UI and SpringFox dependencies from 3.0.0 to 2.9.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note the compiler version issue as below:

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
58 = Java 14
59 = Java 15
60 = Java 16
61 = Java 17
62 = Java 18
63 = Java 19
64 = Java 20
```

if you are using java version 8/11 then below dependency you can use.
Note: springdoc-openapi v1.7.0 is the latest Open Source release supporting Spring Boot 2.x and 1.x.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

use the above dependency and access the api using below sample url.
http://localhost:8765/swagger-ui.html

for Spring-boot v3 (Java 17 & Jakarta EE 9)

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is not able to get the default group name because of a conflict so **just add groupName to the Docket build** like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .groupName("Your-Group-Name");
        return docket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It became working for me after removing  `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: removing it causes `Error creating bean with name webMvcRequestHandlerProvider` among other things...

Answer (score -1):

Faced same issue just resolved with change in dependency
Refer https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-swagger-springfox/

compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"

Previously was using - Not working

compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '3.0.0'

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck for a day with this issue. My issue was incorrect port configuration. Check your `application.yml/application.properties` file for port configuration. There I had mistakenly added both
`server.port , management.server.port` with different values  .